# AWS cognito Json Web Token and Json Web Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, access-token, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I've been playing around with AWS Cognito using the javascript SDK(using GitHub examples from Amazon) in an angular app for the front-end and a .Net Core application for the back-end. What I'm wondering is, and why I can't seem to find out is that it seems that all important information about the access tokens is publicly available. 
For example the User Pool Id, IdentityPoolId and ClientId are just variables in the javascript and therefore available to anyone. Having those variables it should be easy to get the JWK since this is a public amazon webpage based on clientid and userpool id. Aren't these keys supposed to be private? And if these keys are publicly available isn't it possible to mimic a login page and steal login information?

I tried searching for stuff like how to protect your key and JWK but when I do I only get results on how to sign and decrypt access_tokens.

**Client Secret**

As the answer below suggest to use the Client secret, I looked into this. The Client Secret is not being used when using the javascript cognito sdk. In documentation they tell you to not generate a secret key because it will not work with the javascript sdk. This because it does not add any extra security since the application runs client side and thus all this information is publicly available.
Its still unclear how secure all these clientid/tokens is since everything can be found online.

**My solution**

If any1 is interested in my solution here it is: So basically what i missed using JWT and JWKS is that a JWK can only be used to validate the JWT signature. It is not possible to use JWK to sign tokens, in case of Amazon the signing of the JWT is done by a certificate somewhere within the idp of cognito. Therefor having access to the JWK is not really a security issue.
Mimicking a login page and using my cognito id's would still be possible but there are other ways of adding security to that.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a user pool app client on AWS Cognito they is an option to *Generate client secret* , The client secret is used to secure your user pool to only authorized applications(those that use the secret key).

The **client secret** is part of the oauth standard, you read more about it [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/)

It is used along with your ClientId and poolId

```
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : '...', // your user pool id here
    ClientId : '...' // your app client id here
    Secretkey: '...'// your app secret key here
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that option and im using that for server-to-server authentication but im not able to use this in the aws-javascript-sdk. Also even if i was able to use this, would it just be another variable that is stored in the javascript and thus exposed publicly?

Answer (score 0):

When you use java-script app, you *must* use client secret key, because that is what provides security.

So when all your other information is public, such as User pool id, client id, etc, a malicious user cannot make call to AWS Cognito and obtain keys because of the missing piece in the puzzle that is the client secret key.

Comment: So how would i use that secret key? The aws-javascript-sdk does not support secret key because of the reasons i mentioned. That means i would have to do server-to-server calls and provide the secret key but then using the aws-javascript-sdk has no point at all.

Comment: @blaataap Ah ok, I get it now. Yeah even I'm not sure what be the best usecase for the aws-javascript-sdk then.